# How do I work with binary data in Java?

Tags: java, binary

I'm working on a simple VM/interpreter kind of program for a simple toy language I implemented. Currently the compiler emits textual assembly instructions such as `push` and `add` to be executed by the VM.

Recently I figured it would be a better idea to actually compile to binary opcodes instead of textual ones, for performance and space. (It doesn't actually matter in this toy project, but this is for learning).

Soon I realized, even though generally I consider myself a decent Java programmer, that I have no idea how to work with binary data in Java. No clue.

Regarding this, I have two questions:

1. How can I save binary data to a file? For example say I want to save the byte `00000001` and then the byte `00100000` to a file (each byte will be an opcode for  the VM) - how can I do that?
2. How can I read binary data from a file on disk, save it in variables, parse it and manipulate it? Do I use the usual I/0 and parsing techniques I use with regular Strings, or is this something different?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). It has a `write(byte[] b)` method to write an array of bytes to a file and a `write(int b)` method to write a single byte to the file.

So, to save `00000001` followed by `00100001`, you can do :

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
file.write(1);
file.write(33);
```

Similarly you can read [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) for reading from a binary file.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a way to write to a byte array *in memory*. OP wants to write binary data *to disk*.

Comment: @DavidConrad My mistake. That's what happens when I rely on my memory before checking the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use *any* [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) to do this, because they all have a `write` method that takes a `byte`. For example, you could use a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Similarly, you can use an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)'s `read` method for reading bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStream` and its subtypes have methods to write bytes to files. `DataOutputStream` has additional methods to write `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc. if you need those, although it writes them in big endian byte order. The corresponding input streams have equivalent methods for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)

Refer to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) for details.

Also, checkout this similar question: [How to output binary data to a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981555/how-to-output-binary-data-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: `ByteArrayInputStream` is for reading from a byte array *in memory*. It does not read from a file *on disk*.

Comment: Reading from the file is just as usual (or via FileUtils by Apache, http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). The interesting part is your point 2 (as long as I understand your question), where you ask how to manipulate the read data.